# How to extract using Xidel all @srcset width strings from an image with @srcset attribute?

Tags: html, bash, srcset, xidel

Using [Xidel](http://www.videlibri.de/xidel.html), I need to extract all the image sizes in an @srcset attribute that contains a common pattern:
"`(\d+)w`"

```
./xidel "url_with_images" -e '?'
```

---

See this image example

```
<img ... @srcset="https://www.jewishpress.com/wp-content/uploads/Billionaire-Arnon-Milchan-and-PM-Benjamin-Netanyahu-696x457.jpg 696w, https://www.jewishpress.com/wp-content/uploads/Billionaire-Arnon-Milchan-and-PM-Benjamin-Netanyahu-220x144.jpg 220w, https://www.jewishpress.com/wp-content/uploads/Billionaire-Arnon-Milchan-and-PM-Benjamin-Netanyahu-300x197.jpg 300w, https://www.jewishpress.com/wp-content/uploads/Billionaire-Arnon-Milchan-and-PM-Benjamin-Netanyahu-768x504.jpg 768w, https://www.jewishpress.com/wp-content/uploads/Billionaire-Arnon-Milchan-and-PM-Benjamin-Netanyahu-475x312.jpg 475w, https://www.jewishpress.com/wp-content/uploads/Billionaire-Arnon-Milchan-and-PM-Benjamin-Netanyahu-741x486.jpg 741w, https://www.jewishpress.com/wp-content/uploads/Billionaire-Arnon-Milchan-and-PM-Benjamin-Netanyahu-640x420.jpg 640w, https://www.jewishpress.com/wp-content/uploads/Billionaire-Arnon-Milchan-and-PM-Benjamin-Netanyahu.jpg 800w" />
```

Xidel Output expected:

```
696w
220w
300w
768w
475w
741w
650w
800w
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.benibela.de/documentation/internettools/xpath-functions.html#x-extract:

> If flags contains *, all occurrences are returned.

```
cat <<EOF | xidel -s - -e 'extract(//@srcset,"(\d+w)",1,"*")'
<img srcset="https://www.jewishpress.com/wp-content/uploads/Billionaire-Arnon-Milchan-and-PM-Benjamin-Netanyahu-696x457.jpg 696w, https://www.jewishpress.com/wp-content/uploads/Billionaire-Arnon-Milchan-and-PM-Benjamin-Netanyahu-220x144.jpg 220w, https://www.jewishpress.com/wp-content/uploads/Billionaire-Arnon-Milchan-and-PM-Benjamin-Netanyahu-300x197.jpg 300w, https://www.jewishpress.com/wp-content/uploads/Billionaire-Arnon-Milchan-and-PM-Benjamin-Netanyahu-768x504.jpg 768w, https://www.jewishpress.com/wp-content/uploads/Billionaire-Arnon-Milchan-and-PM-Benjamin-Netanyahu-475x312.jpg 475w, https://www.jewishpress.com/wp-content/uploads/Billionaire-Arnon-Milchan-and-PM-Benjamin-Netanyahu-741x486.jpg 741w, https://www.jewishpress.com/wp-content/uploads/Billionaire-Arnon-Milchan-and-PM-Benjamin-Netanyahu-640x420.jpg 640w, https://www.jewishpress.com/wp-content/uploads/Billionaire-Arnon-Milchan-and-PM-Benjamin-Netanyahu.jpg 800w" />
EOF

696w
220w
300w
768w
475w
741w
640w
800w
```

`-e 'tokenize(//@srcset,",") ! substring-after(.,"jpg ")'` works too.

Comment: With URL? How to do this with URL? Not using EOT

Comment: How to get the highest resolution from the list?

Comment: You didn't provide an url, so I used the `<img>` element node you provided as raw input. With an url it's as simple as `xidel -s "url" -e 'extract(//@srcset,"(\d+w)",1,"*")'`.